# Generalize min-max scaling to vectors

Tags: normalization, feature-scaling, embeddings

I am combining several vectors, where each vector is a certain kind of embedding of some object. Since each embedding is very different (some have all components between $[0, 1]$ some have components in the range of around 60 or 70 etc.) I want to rescale the vectors before combining them. I thought about using something like min-max rescaling, but I'm not sure how to generalize it to vectors. I could do something of the sort - $\frac{v-|v_{min}|}{|v_{max}|-|v_{min}|)}$ but I don't think it makes much sense. Is there some generalization of min-max scaling for vectors, or generalization of some other kind of scaling?

Comment: One normalization is for example L2 normalization, so $x \rightarrow \frac{x}{||x||}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to [normalize vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Examples). Common examples include:

- Absolute-value norm
- Euclidean norm
- Taxicab norm or Manhattan norm
- p-norm
- Maximum norm

Answer (score 0):

There are many different methods, none of which are going to be the best option all the time. Some maybe you could throw away based on some extra information you didn't provide ... but the real answer is to throw the kitchen sink at it and see which leads to the best performance.